# What percentage of African-American Republicans are conservative?

Tags: united-states, parties, ideology, statistics

I saw a [Gallup article](https://news.gallup.com/poll/225074/conservative-lead-ideology-down-single-digits.aspx) that says that 69% of Republicans overall identify as conservative. I am thinking about a small proportion of Republican voters which is a large proportion of Democratic voters: African-Americans.

I want to know what percentage of those who identify and/or lean Republican identify as conservative. I couldn't find anything on it because that is not a sizeable piece of the electorate.

Comment: How do you define conservative?  Or are you just looking for self-identification?

Comment: Including a numeric guess doesn't seem relevant, at least not without a rationale for each number.

Answer (score 3):

The [2018 Cooperative Congressional Election Study](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/ZSBZ7K) is a large-scale survey project which contains a dataset formed of a nationally representative sample of 60,000 American adults.

Restricting responses to those identifying as 'Black' when asked 'What racial or ethnic group best describes you?', and further restricting these respondents to those who answered Lean Republican, Not very strong Republican, or Strong Republican when asked for their party identification, we are left with 408 respondents.

The dataset includes two questions which can be used to answer your question. Firstly, the 'ideo5' question, which asks "In general, how would you describe your own political viewpoint?", and gives a five-point scale from 'Very liberal', to 'Very conservative', and secondly, the 'CC18_334A' question, which asks 'How would you rate each of the following individuals and groups?: Yourself', and gives a seven-point scale.

The responses to both questions are shown in the bar charts below. Restricting the responses to both questions further to a three-point scale, Liberal, Moderate, and Conservative and excluding 'Not Sure', we get 38:95:249, and 45:58:296 respectively. This relates to approximately **10% liberal, 25% moderate, 65% conservative** in response to 'ideo5', and **11% liberal, 15% moderate, 74% conservative** in response to the finer-grained 'CC18_334A'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A nice example of how framing and adding a "somewhat conservative" option can change the result, in this case from 65 to 74% conservative, even within the same survey.  It is apparent that many who describe as "moderate" also describe themselves as "somewhat conservative". Also it can be noted that there is no significant difference between black republicans and the overall republican population.